# How can I persist changes to Asp.net settings via Remote IIS manager (IIS 7)?

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp.net, remote-access

So I recently found out about how Remote IIS can manage the Asp.net properties of my web site, such as connection strings, smtp settings etc..  Managing it through IIS rather than through web.config transforms means it's much easier to deploy settings without having to store my database connectionstring (with credentials!) in source control, as well as other critical data that's only relevant to the production system but no relevance to development.

However, whenever I add/change settings via Remote IIS, those changes are reverted the next time I publish my site (because remote IIS manager is writing the changes to web.config and thus web.config gets overwritten with my local copy).

Is there any way to get the Asp.net settings that were changed via the Remote IIS Manager to persist after future publishes?

The server is running IIS 7.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the settings in web.config that you want to set in IIS and when you deploy, they will not be overwritten. It sounds like you are leaving the default connection string settings in the web.config file and they are overwriting the IIS settings that you are specifying.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case.  When I deleted my `ConnectionStrings` section from my web.config, and published it to my IIS server, it always overwrites any connection strings I set with the remote IIS manager (as the IIS manager is writing it to web.config, which is being overwritten)

Comment: I would make sure that you are modifying the correct web.config file for your publishing settings. i.e. if you are publishing to prod, make sure you are editing your prod web.config.

Comment: How do I tell remote IIS manager what web.config to edit though?  The issue is that remote IIS manager is updating it's web.config, but the publish action pushes the development web.config up (which is sometimes needed if I have non-prod only settings change) which overwrites any changes made by the Remote IIS Manager

Comment: I meant in visual studio. Since there are different transforms for the different deployment types, make sure you are editing and then deploying the correct web.config.

Comment: Well my point is I don't want to edit this data in visual studio, because that information will then be stored in source control, thus exposing production database passwords and information to all of development.  I was hoping to just keep all the information on the remote IIS server, since it's only relevant in that environment anyway.  I don't want to exclude the transform in source control though because there are other transforms that are required that need to be source controlled and not forgotten (such as settings to NOT recreate the database on model changes)

Comment: try putting some specific string in one of your connection settings from your web.config file in VS and doing a publish to see if the web.config on the server is indeed getting overwritten by VS and not some other process.

Comment: Yep already tried that, it's the actual publishing of an updated web.config that is overwriting my settings created and edited via Remote IIS Manager (connectionstrings, application settings, and smtp settings)

Comment: Ok, I think I am understanding your issue. So you want the settings you specify in the IIS manager console to persist but you also want the web.config settings from VS to apply to that file also? If this is the case, then I don't think that's possible with web deploy. It's going to either write one of the files or the other. AFAIK you can't have your VS web.config file merge its settings in with the server side web.config.